# Find what was printed in the terminal

Tags: c++, dll, printing, terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there anyway to check the terminal (Linux, and Windows) for characters at certain positions? I have external methods loaded via an explicitly loaded dll that prints certain characters onto the screen. I need to see if the functions printed what they were supposed to with minimal cross talk between the between the plugins. So at the core I am wondering if C++ has any feature for pulling chars off of the termial/command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on VT100-like terminals (the kind popular in Linux.)

For Windows I can't say, but if you are using a cygwin terminal (not the power shell or the "DOS shell") the answer is again no.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tmux or screen to set up a virtual terminal.  The display state can then be captured, which seems to be what you want.  But something in my brain is telling me that, whatever you are trying to do, this is probably not the right solution.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I am trying to see if my dll printed the right what I wanted to.

Comment: But what does it do?  Are you trying to test an interactive UI or can you just capture the stream to a file and parse that?

Comment: capturing the stream to a file, but without modifying my dll, any advice?